# How to update value to null using FluentMigrator

Tags: c#, sql-server, fluent-migrator

How can I update all rows to null using FluentMigrator fluent syntax? You cannot assign null to anonymous type property.

```
Update.Table("mytable").Set(new { supplierid = null }).AllRows();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer to my question. You must use `DBNull.Value`.

```
Update.Table("mytable").Set(new { supplierid = DBNull.Value }).AllRows();
```

Comment: Does the following work for you instead? `Update.Table("mytable").Set(new { supplierid = (int?)null }).AllRows();`

Comment: The usage of DBNull.Value was valuable to me also when changing a `NULL` column to a `NOT NULL`. So could do 


 `Update.Table("Test2").InSchema("SchemaName").Set(new { TestBit2 = 32 }).Where(new { TestBit2 = DBNull.Value });`

`Alter.Table("Test2").InSchema("SchemaName").AlterColumn("TestBit2").AsInt32().NotNullable();`

Answer (score 0):

If any one want to use Where condition then try below code.

```
 Update.Table("Tablname")
                .Set(new { Columnname = "value" })
                .Where( new { Columnname = "conditionvalue" } );
```